# How to insert images with text data to database in php using mysql.?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a long-form with some images upload areas. I need to insert images with text data to MySQL database The form and query code as follows. If PHP codes are not correct, **tell me how to do it correctly.?**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form_main">
                <h4 class="heading"><strong>Add</strong> Vehicle <span></span></h4>
                <div class="form">
                <form action="insert.php" method="POST" id="contactFrm" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="contactFrm">
                    <select class="form-control form-control-lg" name="brand">
                      <option value="TATA" >TATA</option>
                      <option value="TOYOTA">TOYOTA</option>
                      <option value="DAIHATSu">DAIHATSU</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Model" name="model" class="txt">           
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Front</label>
                        <input type="file" name="vehi_front" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Left</label>
                        <input type="file" name="vehi_left" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Right</label>
                        <input type="file" name="vehi_right" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Rear</label>
                        <input type="file" name="vehi_back" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
                     </div>
                     <textarea placeholder="Other" name="other" type="text" class="txt_3"></textarea>
                     <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="txt2">
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the insert query code.

```
<?php
include("../inc/conn.php");

$brand=$_POST['brand'];
$model=$_POST['model'];
$vehi_front=$_POST['vehi_front'];
$vehi_left=$_POST['vehi_left'];
$vehi_right=$_POST['vehi_right'];
$vehi_back=$_POST['vehi_back'];
$other=$_POST['other'];
    {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO vehicle(brand,model,vehi_front,vehi_left,vehi_right,vehi_back,other) VALUES ('{$brand}','{$model}','{$vehi_front}','{$vehi_left}','{$vehi_right}','{$vehi_back}','{$other}')";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
    header("location:add_vehicle.php?msg=Successfully Saved !");
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you tried $_FILES global variable?

Comment: to access a file upload in PHP you use `$_FILES['vehi_front']` rather than `$_POST['vehi_front']`

Comment: No. now I am trying to do.

Comment: It has been saved to the database. but images cannot show. Its file extension (.bin)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using `$_FILES` variable

see reference here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score -1):

you must create image uploader function
in php $_POST['image_input_name'] return you null
you must use $_FILE

```
  function uploadPic($file_input_name, $path)
    {
        if (isset($_FILES[$file_input_name])) {
            $file = $_FILES[$file_input_name];
            // for bin2hex and random_bytes you must use php > 7
            $new_name = (string)bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
            $extension = ".jpg";
            $final_name = $new_name . $extension;
            move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path . $final_name);
            return $path . $final_name;

        }
    }
```

first line check for image
2 get the file and put in into $file 
3 change the name for security
4 change the extension for more security
// user upload a shel.php. in function we change the name and extension
// for exp shel.php converted to hs7f4w8r5c1f4s5d9t6g3s149748654asdasd.jpg
5 add name and extension in var
6 we move uploaded pic to path
7 we return the address and name of pic
and in your new code here

```
<?php
include("../inc/conn.php");

$brand = $_POST['brand'];
        $model = $_POST['model'];
        // in if we check for image exist
        if ($_FILES['vehi_front']['tmp_name'] != "") {
            $vehi_front = $this->uploadPic("vehi_front", "/path/to/save/image");
        }
        if ($_FILES['vehi_left']['tmp_name'] != "") {
            $vehi_left = $this->uploadPic("vehi_left", "/path/to/save/image");
        }
        if ($_FILES['vehi_right']['tmp_name'] != "") {
            $vehi_right = $this->uploadPic("vehi_right", "/path/to/save/image");
        }
        if ($_FILES['vehi_back']['tmp_name'] != "") {
            $vehi_right = $this->uploadPic("vehi_back", "/path/to/save/image");
        }


        $other = $_POST['other'];
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO vehicle(brand,model,vehi_front,vehi_left,vehi_right,vehi_back,other) VALUES ('{$brand}','{$model}','{$vehi_front}','{$vehi_left}','{$vehi_right}','{$vehi_back}','{$other}')";
            if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
                header("location:add_vehicle.php?msg=Successfully Saved !");
            }
        }
?>
```